# The word "miracle" suggests, through common usage, a positive thing. Has it always? Or, like "awe", did it used to simply mean "momentous"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, latin

Oxford asserts the word comes to us from Latin's *miraculum*, or an ‘object of wonder’, which in turn derives from *mirari* (‘to wonder’), itself a conjugation of *mirus* (‘wonderful’).

Since "wonder", when used as a noun, simply describes a feeling of awe at experiencing something new - which is not necessarily a positive; one can feel wonder at the breadth of human cruelty during the Spanish Inquisition. "Awe" is covered by the term "shock" often as not.

The Catholic church, however, rather subsumed and held a monopoly on the "miraculous" for millennia. But I wonder: were there, at some point in human history, "dark" miracles? Or has the word always carried with it the suggestion of divinity and joyous revelation?

Comment: Millennia? The 'catholic Church' predates this usage, but the appellation 'the Catholic Church' was first used by Saint Cyril of Jerusalem around about 350 CE to distinguish it from other groups that also called themselves 'the Church'.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're driving at. Do you disapprove of my use of the "millennia", "Catholic", or "church"? All I'd intended there was to say "an organized religion" (denomination is superfluous) appears to have claimed a near monopoly on its use, and has thusly brought it up into contemporary lexicon as a positive thing. But an atom bomb could be said to be an "object of wonder", and indeed, its results miraculous, in the "surprising or difficult to accept" connotation. I'm simply curious if this is a result of the church adopting it as their own, or if it was always seen positively.

Comment: 'Millennia' means 'thousands of years' and is rare enough for a hyperbolic fuzzy-quantifier-type usage not to be idiomatic (contrast "I've had hundreds of phone calls this morning"). So 2000 years (more likely 3000 years) or over.

Comment: There is the term "negative miracle" mentioned in some books and it is described as the negative use of divine power. There is also references to "white vs black magic" when comparing miracles and negative miracles. One of the sources: [_Miracle and Magic_ by Andy Reimer](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Miracle_and_Magic/23Ik__xXRnMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22negative+miracle%22&pg=PA107&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @Andy Reimer: EXCELLENT citation - what a great find! It does seems to support the premise prompting my question, though:
"It is sometimes the case that positive or negative use of divine power [...] is seen as a boundary marker between magic and miracle. [...] results in an unnecessary exculpation of the miracle-workers in Acts who perform "punitive" miracles, or conversely, brings forward the suggestion that these are a case of the miracle-worker operating as a magician."
It suggests a "negative miracle" is, by its nature, reclassified as "magic". I ordered a copy, either way! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, the word is heavily associated with what the Christian god does. However, the devil also is said to perform "miracles":

> Þe tauerne ys þe scole of þe dyeule..þer huer he makeþ his miracles, zuiche ase behoueþ to þe dyeule. — Ayenbite of Inwyt, 1340

[Translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59399/59399-h/59399-h.htm): "The tavern is the school of the devil... where he does his miracles, such as it behoves the devil (to do)."

In the next sentence, the devil's miracles are contrasted with god's.

The antichrist also is said to perform miracles. The term "false miracle" is sometimes used instead, such as in [some translations of the Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/2%20Thessalonians%202%3A9).

There are also plenty of examples of (usually good) miracles being associated with non-Christian figures such as pagan gods and Mohammed ("Mahomet").

See the [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED27879/track?counter=1&search_id=11905880) for some more examples.

Comment: That is a thorough and well-researched response, @Laurel! If I may ask - not to in any way impugn the veracity of your answer, but please: indulge me - do we know of any references to it outside of religious texts? I know that's asking a LOT, considering the Church's relationship to literacy, particularly through the Dark Ages. I've managed to find no mention of it in any of the Ptolemaic, Greek, or Latin texts I've searched. Quite literally: I've ONLY found it used in Judeo-Christian contexts. I cannot help but wonder if they themselves didn't coin the term and introduce it to the zeitgeist.

Comment: @NerdyDeeds The Chaucer quotes from the Knight's Tale would be a good example, as he uses it to refer to miracles done by Love and Pluto. And in the Franklin's tale, someone's praying to "Lord Phebus", or Apollo for a miracle. (All quoted in the MED.)

Comment: Well-spotted! And yields enough to be moving ahead with! Sold!

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you define "miracle". If you see it as an act by a deity that defies the laws of science then it seems that the plagues allegedly visited upon Egypt were miracles.

Job's troubles were all caused by the miracle of God's conniving with Satan to permit experiments on humans.

The miracle of the destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah is an outstanding miracle, but is beaten easily by the Noahide Flood in which the entire population of the earth (save eight people) was killed.

2 Kings 19:35 tells of the miracle in which 185,000 Assyrian soldiers were killed by an angel.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/connive): << _connive to do something: Conspire to do something immoral, illegal, or harmful._ >> Blasphemous, and showing a lack of even a basic appreciation of theodicy. Job eventually approached a realisation of this reality. Not that I'm claiming to have got as far.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are few who would disagree that what apparently happened to Job was not *immoral, illegal, **and** harmful* You do really need to re-read the folk tale of Job and exchange God and Satan with, for example, 2 modern day politicians. Then you would need to imagine what people would think of it. The theodicy is no more than cheap apologetics.

Comment: @Greybeard: well, yes: the question is ABOUT how we define "miracle". What I'm seeking is some indication, or suggestion, or heavily-veiled hint that the word may have been in use prior to the Church seizing on it as an all-purpose label for anything that had a whiff of JDVH attached to it. This is just a point of academic curiosity for me, mind... after all: there's no way to prove the negative here. Heh. I'd go so far as to say, the in the context of the question, arguing the merits of apologetics in general serves only to further conflate the miraculous with the divine, theodicy in itself.

Comment: @NerdyDeeds Old English did not have the word "miracle": The noun was "wundor"  *a circumstance or act that excites astonishment*, i.e. more of less today's use, and was not especially associated with religion. Beowulf: Þá wæs **wundor** micel þæt se wínsele wiðhæfde heaþodéorum· -> Then it was a great wonder that the wine-hall withstood the war-fighters and we also have *searowundor* - strange wonder; *níðwundor* horrible wonder.

Comment: That's as may be... but *LATIN* did (miraculum, mirari, mirus). That having been said, however, your most recent response is what I've been looking into. Just as "awesome" - which, in its modern context, is virtually always used in a positive connotation - once simply meant an "event inspiring awe", which itself used to be entirely flexible in its positivity. Everything from teeth-chattering existential dread to rapturous ecclesiastic joy could be considered a form of "awe". But the Catholic church seized on "miracle, elevating it, and I cannot tell if it was ALWAYS positively-spun prior.